# Better way of looping over a SQL result set

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm just wondering if there's a better way to perform a SQL query over another SQL result set that I'm storing in an instance variable.

My code looks like this:

```
def index
  id = current_user.id.to_s

  #First SQL query
  @messages = Message.where("user_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", id, id).group('recipient_id')
end
```

And in the view I have

```
<% @messages.each do |m| %>
<!-- Second SQL query -->
<% r = Tutor.find(m.recipient_id).user %>
  <%= "#{r.first_name + ' ' + r.last_name}" %><br />
  <%= m.subject %><br />
  <%= m.body %><br />
  <%= m.user_id %><br />
  <%= m.recipient_id %><br />
<% end %>
```

I'm looping over @messages, and then doing a SQL query on each of those objects as well and I'm wondering if there's a better (smarter) way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you want a group on that -- do you mean order perhaps?

Comment: No, group is fine for this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ActiveRecord association between `Message` and `Tutor`. I would need to take a look at your models to say exactly how to relate them, but you're basically doing the association work yourself instead of offloading it to AR/SQL.

Once you have the proper relationship in place, you would see something along these lines.

In your controller:

```
def index
  id = current_user.id
  @messages = Message.includes(:tutor).where("user_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", id, id).group(:recipient_id)
end
```

In your view:

```
<% @messages.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.tutor.user.to_s %><br />
  <%= m.subject %><br />
  <%= m.body %><br />
  <%= m.user_id %><br />
  <%= m.recipient_id %><br />
<% end %>
```

In your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: @DaniG2k The main point about this answer is using `includes(:tutor)`. This is called [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) and prevents n+1 queries when loading associated records.

Comment: By the way, I don't think `"#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"` should be in `Tutor`. It'd be better to put that in a `fullname` method in `User` and do `m.tutor.user.fullname` (IMO).

Comment: Although probably he should use STI for the "relationship" between `User` and `Tutor`, not `User belongs_to :tutor` and `Tutor :has_one :user` like he seems to be doing now. But that is another question...

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions guys! Yes, ideally it should be m.tutor.user.fullname.
My model relationships are set up like this right now:
`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :tutor, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages
end`
`class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end`
and
`class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tutor
end`
How can I set this up so that I can simply do m.tutor.user ?? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Yes, and I've changed my model so that I can do m.tutor.user now and it works fine! Thanks :D